# Explicit wait utility

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, appium, webdriverwait

I am using one generic explicit wait utility which can be used in different places in my test case. Following is the code I have written for the same under Base Test. Here I am looking for a text to present in the screen.For that I have given the parameter "text" in the function VerifyTextPresence.

But after running the script, I am having the below error. How to make it generic so that for any text, I can use this utility. For example, here I am checking for the text "Get" to be present in the screen

Utility Code:

```
def VerifyTextPresence(self,text):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15)
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 'new UiSelector().text(text)'))).text
```

Test Script:

```
def test_testcasename(self):
        self.VerifyTextPresence("Get")
```

Error:

```
io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiSelectorSyntaxException: Could not parse expression `new UiSelector().textGet`: No opening parenthesis after method name at position
```

Comment: You've tagged python and you are using `new UiSelector()`?

Comment: using appium with Python..Ui selector is a Java class but can be used also. Like java script executor we use in selenium-python

Comment: At least `text` argument from python method should be injected to selector: `'new UiSelector().text("' + text + '")'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Appium docs

https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/uiautomator-uiselector/

UiSelector for text should look like:

```
new UiSelector().text("some text value")
```

and in your example:

```
new UiSelector().text(text)
```

I see 2 issues here:

- no quotes for text
- no reference to python method text arg

also

- `element = (...).text` will put the text value to element, and looks not helpful.

Try this:

```
def VerifyTextPresence(self, text):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, f"new UiSelector().text(\"{text}\")")))
```